# Print text between two strings - omit second occurrence

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have an instruction file with a lot of steps. I'd want to view a single desired step in a shell, without graphical environment. What I do right now, as pointed out by [alemol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16999848/3101837), is using `sed` to extract what's inside the number of the step I'd like to view and the next one.

```
cat file | sed -n '/12/,/13/p'
```

> Step 12: something
>   `commands to execute`
>   Step 13: something else

What I miss to make it do exactly what I want is omitting the last line: what `sed` do is print from first occurrence to second, including those. I'd want to avoid the second, removing last line from output and printing just

> Step 12: something
>   `commands to execute`

How do I modify my command to achieve that?
I'd prefer no additional commands, pipelines and such. If it's possible, I'd just want to modify the `sed` use I make (or an equally straightforward single use of some other tool like `grep`), differentiating the first pattern from the second, such as "print one but omit the other".

Also, I'd want the command to be as easy as possible, so that I can memorize it without huge effort, and write it in little time.

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks, it is more than perfect. You can write that as an answer, I will definitely accept it.

Comment: Jeff, you're welcome - this has been asked before, I just don't have the time to search for it right now.

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Don_crissti gave you one solution in the comments (and I will follow his file [naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)):

```
sed -n '/12/,/13/{/13/!p}' UUoC.txt
```

That will select all lines from the first `12` to the first `13` in the file `UUoC.txt`, and print them unless they match `13` (that's what `/13/!p` does).

Another approach would be to use `head` to discard the last line:

```
sed -n '/12/,/13/p' file.txt | head -n -1
```

Comment: or `sed '$d'` to discard last line

Answer (score 1):

don_crissti and terdon did all the hard work; I saw this question and wanted to suggest using a shell function to further reduce typing / memorization, and perhaps add some flexibility. While typing it up, I've also taken the liberty of tightening down the regular expression some, to avoid false positives.

Here's the shell function:

```
function step () (
  STEPS=./steps.txt
  start=$1
  stop=$((start+1))
  sed -n "/^Step $start:/,/^Step $stop:/ { /^Step $stop:/ !p }" $STEPS
)
```

You're obviously free to name it whatever you like; `step` seemed intuitive to me based on the wording of the instruction file. Adjust the `STEPS` variable to be the full path to the actual instruction file; that way, you don't have to remember -- or type! -- the path to that file at the command-line. I made the function use a subshell -- parens around the body instead of braces -- because I didn't want to pollute your shell's namespace with the STEPS, start, and stop variables. If creating a subshell is more bothersome than three new variables, feel free to change the second set of parenthesis over to curly braces.

I did two basic things to the regular expression that don & terdon used:

1. Forced the match to start at the beginning of the line, and
2. required it to contain the word "Step" followed by the number, followed by a colon.

I did both of those things because I can imagine the instruction file potentially containing numbers inside the `commands to execute` and so causing the simpler regex to falsely match.

Here's the "devil's advocate" steps.txt file I was using:

```
Step 1: one
commands to execute
Step 2: two
commands to execute
commands to execute
Step 3: three
commands to execute skip to Step 7
Step 4: four
commands to execute not step 5
commands to execute
commands to execute
commands to execute
Step 5: five
commands to execute
commands to execute
commands to execute skip to Step 6:
commands to execute
Step 6: six
commands to execute
Step 7: seven
commands to execute
Step 8: eight
commands to execute
Step 9: nine
commands to execute
Step 10: ten
commands to execute
Step 11: eleven
commands to execute
Step 12: something
commands to execute
commands to execute
Step 13: something else
commands to execute
```

... and the results of a test harness (the output from `step 14` is empty):

```
$ for step in $(seq 1 14); do step $step; echo; done
Step 1: one
commands to execute

Step 2: two
commands to execute
commands to execute

Step 3: three
commands to execute skip to Step 7

Step 4: four
commands to execute not step 5
commands to execute
commands to execute
commands to execute

Step 5: five
commands to execute
commands to execute
commands to execute skip to Step 6:
commands to execute

Step 6: six
commands to execute

Step 7: seven
commands to execute

Step 8: eight
commands to execute

Step 9: nine
commands to execute

Step 10: ten
commands to execute

Step 11: eleven
commands to execute

Step 12: something
commands to execute
commands to execute

Step 13: something else
commands to execute
```